# How to authenticate EC2 instance with AWS ALB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

AWS Application Load Balancers (ALB) support authentication: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/built-in-authentication-in-alb/.

The documentation talks about human users - users arriving at the ALB are redirected to an Identity Provider (IdP) if they are unauthenticated.

Does ALB support authenticating EC2 instances? i.e. how can I ensure that only certain EC2 instances can access a service that resides behind an ALB?